# Obtener ID de una nueva inserción en la base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy buscando recuperar el id que se acaba de crear con el siguente query, para poderlo usar en otro query, a lo cuál me retorna un error de este tipo `[42601] ERROR: subquery must return only one column`, alguna sugerencia para poder obtener ese id directamente del insert.

```
declare
    idNuevo integer;
begin
     insert into
                schema.mitabla (id, datox, datoy)
          values
                (default, $1, $2) returning id into idNuevo;
     insert into 
                schema.miOtraTabla (idDeEstaTabla, idMiTabla)
          values
                (default, idNuevo);
     commit
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambia tu línea

```
returning id into idnuevo
```

A

```
returning id as idnuevo
```